# filter h1 tag to add a word at the beginning of the text

Tags: the-content

I'm looking for the best way to obtain this.

For example, I have the h1 tag whic is: **Web Design**

I want to add, in all the h1 tags of a **certain post type**, the same word at the beginning, which is my keyword. So, the result would be: **MYKEYWORD Web Design**

I have clear that I have to use the_content filter. I have this code:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'handle_h1' );

function handle_h1( $content )
{
    //check if it's the post type which I look for
    if (  'MYPOSTTYPE' != get_post_type() )
        return $content;


    return str_ireplace( '<h1', '<a href="#">Back to the top</a><h1', $content );
}
```

The example above adds the a href tag before the h1 tags...

Which I want is to change the output text of the h1, as I mentioned above.

EXAMPLE:

**Original:**

```
<h1>Books</h1>
```

**What I want**

```
<h1>Our Books</h1>
```

So the word added is "Our".

Comment: Do you want to add that to ever `h1` HTML tag that wraps _anything_ in your content (not the post type title or other parts)?

Comment: In these posts types, I only have one h1 tag in the page, and I want to append the word MYKEYWORD just before the h1 text <h1>MYKEYWORD text...</h1> Thanks!

Comment: Again: In the content or the title or some meta field? Please update your question with an [edit] and give us (a) an example text to test on and (b) show us the template/loop contents where this should happen.

Comment: I just edited my question. I want to add to ever h1 of a custom post type.

Comment: Daniel, it seems that you do not understand me fully. Could you ask a friend who speaks better English for help on answering my questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_title', 10, 2 );   
function change_title( $title, $postid ) {

    global $post;

    if( get_post_type() == MYPOSTTYPE && $title == $post->post_title ){            

        $title = "MYKEYWORD ".$title;            
    }

    return $title;
}
```